# how to get json result from payfort Apis in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, payfort

The problem I am facing is that, payfort API should return me some json. But instead i get some html that has some hidden fields. and i see no error written inside there.

Here is my code

```
string access_code = string.Empty,
            amount = string.Empty,
            currency = string.Empty,
            customer_email = string.Empty,
            merchant_reference = string.Empty,
            order_description = string.Empty,
            language = string.Empty,
            merchant_identifier = string.Empty,
            signature = string.Empty,
            command = string.Empty;

        access_code = "X78979879h8h8h8";
        amount = "1000";
        command = "AUTHORIZATION";
        currency = "AED";
        customer_email = "zetawars@hotmail.com";
        language = "en";
        merchant_identifier = "RaskdQuCc";
        merchant_reference = "ASASASASASADSS";
        order_description = "Some order details";
        signature = "";

        string signature_string = "PASSaccess_code="+access_code+"amount="+amount+"command="+command+"currency="+currency+"customer_email"+customer_email+"language"+language+"merchant_identifier"+merchant_identifier+"merchant_reference"+merchant_reference+"order_description"+order_description+"PASS";

        signature = getHashSha256(signature_string);
        string url = "https://sbcheckout.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentPage";
        string param = "access_code" + access_code + "&amount=" + amount + "&currency=" + currency + 
            "&customer_email=" + customer_email + "&merchant_reference=" + merchant_reference + 
            "&order_description=" + order_description + "&language=" + language + "merchant_identifier=" 
            + merchant_identifier + "&signature=" + signature + "&command=" + command;


        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            //wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(url, param);
        }
```

Comment: did you find any solutions . i face the same issue now . does this code send the parameters to the api and receive data from it . or only send . if it is only send how do i receive the response after sending the request .

Answer (score 2):

Try adding values for below header

```
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization]
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.TenantId]
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Client-Type]
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Protocol]
```

Works for me!!

Comment: what values should i add here

Comment: that could be provided by the people who provided you the web-service.

Answer (score 0):

First Encode the response

```
string responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
```

Use HtmlDocument (HtmlAgilityPack)

```
var html = new HtmlDocument();
var tokenValue = "";
html.LoadHtml(responseString);
```

After Loading This into html you can query fields and values.

```
var tokenFormIdElement = 
          html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='token']");
tokenValue = tokenFormIdElement.GetAttributeValue("value", "");
```